# How can I implement a large relational database schema on a basic key value store?

Tags: relational-database, key-value

How can I implement a large relational database schema on a key value store?

The following are the requirements:

1) uses no stored procedures or special database vendor specific features

2) Uses indexes

3) Uses joins

4) Many complex types in tables (VARCHAR, INT, BLOB, etc)

5) Billions of records

6) Full text search

7) Timestamped backup possible

8) Transactions not needed (atomic single row/field updates only)

Comment: Sounds like an awfully bad idea to me. You obviously need a lot of RDBMS features, so please, for god's sake, use an RDMBS.

Comment: I've tried RDBMS but performance really starts to such after a few 10s of million of rows. The problem ends up that we have to do sharding and lots of other special tricks which end up very expensive money wise because of the complexity of creating these solutions and the maintenance. I guess there are no alternatives to an RDBMS then.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to, in essence, build your own relational database system. Without it, joins will be horribly slow (no query optimizer). You can get full text search by grafting on Lucene.

Have you considered an open source RDBMS (e.g. Derby)?

Comment: Well, I don't need transactions which is a large part of what databases do. But Lucene looks like it might have a place in what I want to do.

Comment: @Zubair Query optimization is another other large part of what they do. If you have only simple joins, then you might not need it.

Comment: Yes, I guess that makes sense what you are saying if I only need simple joins then I am ok. Does this mean that key-value stores are not so good as complex reporting systems which often use multi level joins?

Answer (score 1):

Often, the whole point of a key-value store is to get away from the constraints of relational databases, but it sounds like you want them back here. Everybody wants to have their cake and eat it too, but I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish here. if you want the power of a relational database, you should use a relational database.

That said, you may want to take a look at **[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)**, which represents a very good compromise between the rigid, structured nature of relational databases and the more free-form approach of a key-value store.

Comment: Yes, I've seen Mongo. Right now I'm seeing MongoDB, Cassandra, and Riak as possible contenders. But I still need to use some solid practices whichever store I choose.

Comment: And, yes, I do want my cake and to eat it :)